# disable button when it expires

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button that currently alerts the user if the coupon has already been download or is expired. How do I implement so that if it is expired, instead of returning an alert, it disables the button instead? Currently the following is my button.

```
<?php
    if (isset ( $entry["couponId"] )) { 
    if(! isset($_SESSION["loginSuccess"])) { ?>
    <button type="submit" value="Coupon" class="disabledbuttonlink" id="couponButton-<?php echo $entry['id']; ?>">Log in to download</button>
    <?php
    } else {
?>
    <button type="submit" value="Coupon" class="buttonlink" id="couponButton-<?php echo $entry['id']; ?>">Coupon</button>
<?php } }?>
```

Below is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    foreach($resultAllPosts['lists'] as $entry){?>
        $('#couponButton-<?php echo $entry['id']; ?>').click(function(){
            if ("<?php echo $sessionId?>" == "<?php echo $non_login_user?>") {
            alert("Please log in to download coupons");
            } else {
    <?php
        $fields = array(
            'projectId' => $PROJECT_ID,
            'sessionId' => $sessionId,                      
            'promotionId' => $entry['couponId']
        );

    $downloadedCoupon = get_decoded_info( $SERVER_URL, $PORT, 'tos-member/user/membershipcoupon/download' , $fields );

    if($downloadedCoupon['message'] != ('Same CouponId downloaded before.' || 'Coupon is expired.' || 'Invalid Coupon.')){              
                    ?>
    window.location = "<?php echo $base_url; ?>coupon-singleview?id=<?php echo $entry["couponId"];?>";
    <?php           
    } else {
    if($downloadedCoupon['message'] == 'Same CouponId downloaded before.'){
    echo "alert('Coupon has already been downloaded');";    ?>
    <?php } else if ($downloadedCoupon['message'] == 'Coupon is expired.') {
    echo "alert('Coupon is expired');";
    } else {
    echo "alert('Invalid coupon.');";
            }
        }
    ?>
    }});
    <?php }?>
</script>
```

I have tried the following to disable the element by javascript but it does not 
work.

```
...
<?php } else if ($downloadedCoupon['message'] == 'Coupon is expired.') {?>
    document.getElementById('couponButton-<?php echo $entry['id']; ?>').disabled = true;
<?php } else {
...
```

Comment: Why don't you just set `disabled` on the element with php? `<button<?php echo ($downloadedCoupon['message'] == 'Coupon is expired.') ? ' disabled' : ''; ?> ...>Coupon</button>`

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery you can change the attribute disabled.

```
$('#couponButton').prop("disabled", true);
```